# Как во время перебора массива удалить из него элементы, не удовлетворяющие условию?

Tags: javascript, массивы, foreach

Есть два массива входящий и изменяемый (ну а третий -  объект просто используется для наполнения второго, не принципиально).

В рабочем по мере обхода нужно выполнять некоторые функции с его элементами, а после удалять,если те пересеклись с ключами во втором (наполняемом):

```js
//входящий массив, его и будем перебирать
var filter_items = ["field_type_commece:107", "field_rooms:25", "field_rooms:27", "field_apartment_type:oldbuild"];

//наполняемый массив
//одновременно с этим массивам будет сверяться верхний filter_items если в этом массиве есть такие ключи, то надо их верхнего удалить соответствующие элементы
var url_synonyms = [];
url_synonyms['field_transaction_type'] = '';
url_synonyms['field_catalog'] = '';
url_synonyms['field_apartment_type'] = '';
url_synonyms['field_type_commece'] = '';


//объект переводов
var url_items = {}
url_items.field_transaction_type = {};
url_items.field_catalog = {};
url_items.field_apartment_type = {};
url_items.field_type_commece = {};

url_items.field_transaction_type['100'] = 'buy';
url_items.field_transaction_type['99'] = 'rent';

url_items.field_catalog['23'] = 'apartment';
url_items.field_catalog['93'] = 'room';
url_items.field_catalog['24'] = 'house';
url_items.field_catalog['68'] = 'commerce';
url_items.field_catalog['94'] = 'land';
url_items.field_catalog['95'] = 'garage';

url_items.field_apartment_type['oldbuild'] = 'oldbuild';
url_items.field_apartment_type['newbuild'] = 'newbuild';

url_items.field_type_commece['96'] = 'office';
url_items.field_type_commece['97'] = 'merchant';
url_items.field_type_commece['98'] = 'stock';
url_items.field_type_commece['102'] = 'production';
url_items.field_type_commece['104'] = 'ready-business';
url_items.field_type_commece['105'] = 'free-room';
url_items.field_type_commece['106'] = 'сar-service';
url_items.field_type_commece['107'] = 'hotel';

filter_items.forEach(function(item, key) {
  var f_item_arr = item.split(':');
  if (url_synonyms.indexOf(f_item_arr[0]) != -1) {
    filter_items.splice(key, 1);
    url_synonyms[f_item_arr[0]] = '/' + url_items[f_item_arr[0]][f_item_arr[1]];
  }
})
console.log(filter_items);
```

Но по мере обхода второй массив изменяется и из за этого ключи не соответствуют реальным позициям в массиве.

Как изменить код, чтобы из второго массива удалились все элементы, которые пересеклись с первым

Comment: для фильтрации массива есть специальный метод [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное вот так:

```js
//входящий массив, его и будем перебирать
var filter_items = ["field_type_commece:107", "field_rooms:25", "field_rooms:27", "field_apartment_type:oldbuild"];

//наполняемый массив
//одновременно с этим массивам будет сверяться верхний filter_items если в этом массиве есть такие ключи, то надо их верхнего удалить соответствующие элементы
var url_synonyms = {};
url_synonyms['field_transaction_type'] = '';
url_synonyms['field_catalog'] = '';
url_synonyms['field_apartment_type'] = '';
url_synonyms['field_type_commece'] = '';


//объект переводов
var url_items = {}
url_items.field_transaction_type = {};
url_items.field_catalog = {};
url_items.field_apartment_type = {};
url_items.field_type_commece = {};

url_items.field_transaction_type['100'] = 'buy';
url_items.field_transaction_type['99'] = 'rent';

url_items.field_catalog['23'] = 'apartment';
url_items.field_catalog['93'] = 'room';
url_items.field_catalog['24'] = 'house';
url_items.field_catalog['68'] = 'commerce';
url_items.field_catalog['94'] = 'land';
url_items.field_catalog['95'] = 'garage';

url_items.field_apartment_type['oldbuild'] = 'oldbuild';
url_items.field_apartment_type['newbuild'] = 'newbuild';

url_items.field_type_commece['96'] = 'office';
url_items.field_type_commece['97'] = 'merchant';
url_items.field_type_commece['98'] = 'stock';
url_items.field_type_commece['102'] = 'production';
url_items.field_type_commece['104'] = 'ready-business';
url_items.field_type_commece['105'] = 'free-room';
url_items.field_type_commece['106'] = 'сar-service';
url_items.field_type_commece['107'] = 'hotel';

filter_items = filter_items.filter(function(item) {
  var f_item_arr = item.split(':');
  let conatins = url_synonyms[f_item_arr[0]] !== undefined;
  if (conatins) 
    url_synonyms[f_item_arr[0]] = '/' + url_items[f_item_arr[0]][f_item_arr[1]];
  return conatins;
})
console.log(filter_items);
console.log(url_synonyms);
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого есть [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var fruits = ['Яблоки', 'Груши', 'Бананы', 'Апельсины', 'Мандарины', 'Гранаты'];
var del_els = ['Апельсины', 'Орехи', 'Помидоры', 'Груши', 'Яблоки', 'Вишня'];
del_els = del_els.filter(function(item, key) {
   return !~fruits.indexOf(item)
})
console.log(fruits);
console.log(del_els);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Извините, все таки пришлось изменить вопрос, понял, что объяснил не совсем правильно, по сути у меня два массива, в одном есть элементы а другом помоложе ключи, они отличаются тем что в первом есть еще и разделители в виде двоеточия. Я выполняют перебор, внутри которого у меня еще собирается строка

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов а обязательно менять массив по ходу итерации, или можно составить новый?)

Comment: Да, в принципе можно новый, но у меня строка собирается из одного массива, дальше, после того как я собрал часть строки, я хотел продолжить собрать её из остатоков этого же массива но уже запустив новый перебор. Почище получилось бы)  сборку строки уже не стал сюда помещать. Наверное так  и надо сделать (собрать новы массив из необработанных элементов)